# Android Wear Watch Face Development Colors

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to develop watch faces, and I was able to add the time, date, and other information and position the text. I had trouble with style, mostly color. I have one red text, and another white text. After going to Ambient Mode and turning back to interactive mode, the color is either white or gray depending on the code below. I can only get it to return to one color.

SimpleWatchFaceService.java

```
package com.me.me.androidwearweather;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceStyle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SimpleWatchFaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new SimpleEngine();
    }

    private class SimpleEngine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {

        private final long TICK_PERIOD_MILLIS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);
        private Handler timeTick;
        private SimpleWatchFace watchFace;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onCreate(holder);

            setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(SimpleWatchFaceService.this)
                    .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)
                    .setAmbientPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.AMBIENT_PEEK_MODE_HIDDEN)
                    .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                    .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                    .build());
            timeTick = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());
            startTimerIfNecessary();
            watchFace = SimpleWatchFace.newInstance(SimpleWatchFaceService.this);

        }

        private void startTimerIfNecessary() {
            timeTick.removeCallbacks(timeRunnable);
            if (isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode()) {
                timeTick.post(timeRunnable);
            }
        }

        private final Runnable timeRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onSecondTick();

                if (isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode()) {
                    timeTick.postDelayed(this, TICK_PERIOD_MILLIS);
                }
            }
        };

        private void onSecondTick() {
            invalidateIfNecessary();
        }

        private void invalidateIfNecessary() {
            if (isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode()) {
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            startTimerIfNecessary();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
            super.onDraw(canvas, bounds);
            watchFace.draw(canvas, bounds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
            super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
            watchFace.setAntiAlias(!inAmbientMode);
            watchFace.setColor(inAmbientMode ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
            // THIS IS WERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS I tried the method on top and bottom of this comment
            // if(inAmbientMode){
                // watchFace.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            // }
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeTick() {
            super.onTimeTick();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            timeTick.removeCallbacks(timeRunnable);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    }
}
```

SimpleWatchFace.java

```
package com.me.me.androidwearweather;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.format.Time;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SimpleWatchFace {

    private final Paint timePaint;
    private final Paint datePaint;
    private final Time time;

    public static SimpleWatchFace newInstance(Context context) {
        Paint timePaint = new Paint();
        timePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        timePaint.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.time_size));
        timePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        Paint datePaint = new Paint();
        datePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        datePaint.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.date_size));
        datePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        return new SimpleWatchFace(timePaint, datePaint, new Time());
    }

    SimpleWatchFace(Paint timePaint, Paint datePaint, Time time) {
        this.timePaint = timePaint;
        this.datePaint = datePaint;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        time.setToNow();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat twelvehour = new SimpleDateFormat("h");
        SimpleDateFormat ampm = new SimpleDateFormat("a");
        String TimeAmPmNoSec = String.format("%2s:%02d %2s", twelvehour.format(cal.getTime()), time.minute, ampm.format(cal.getTime()));
        float timeXOffset = computeXOffset(TimeAmPmNoSec, timePaint, bounds);
        float timeYOffset = computeTimeYOffset(TimeAmPmNoSec, timePaint, bounds);
        canvas.drawText(TimeAmPmNoSec, timeXOffset, timeYOffset, timePaint);

        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        SimpleDateFormat day_text = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
        String DateNew = String.format("%s | %s %02d", day_text.format(cal.getTime()), month_date.format(cal.getTime()), time.monthDay);

        float dateXOffset = computeXOffset(DateNew, datePaint, bounds);
        float dateYOffset = computeDateYOffset(DateNew, datePaint);
        canvas.drawText(DateNew, dateXOffset, timeYOffset + dateYOffset, datePaint);
    }
    private float computeXOffset(String text, Paint paint, Rect watchBounds) {
        float centerX = watchBounds.exactCenterX();
        float timeLength = paint.measureText(text);
        return centerX - (timeLength / 2.0f);
    }

    private float computeTimeYOffset(String timeText, Paint timePaint, Rect watchBounds) {
        float centerY = watchBounds.exactCenterY();
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        timePaint.getTextBounds(timeText, 0, timeText.length(), textBounds);
        int textHeight = textBounds.height();
        return centerY + (textHeight / 2.0f) - 50f;
    }

    private float computeDateYOffset(String dateText, Paint datePaint) {
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        datePaint.getTextBounds(dateText, 0, dateText.length(), textBounds);
        return textBounds.height() + 25f;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean antiAlias) {
        timePaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
        datePaint.setAntiAlias(antiAlias);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        timePaint.setColor(color);
        datePaint.setColor(color);
    }
}
```

I was also wondering if it is possible to style a text with more than one font and color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2: Alright, you could just instantiate a new watch face each time the mode is changed (Java will automatically garbage collect the old one, so no worries on memory) OR, I personally would do this.

Add two new functions in your SimpleWatchFace class to replace your **setColor** function

```
public void setTimeColor(int color) {
        timePaint.setColor(color);
}

public void setDateColor(int color) {
        datePaint.setColor(color);
}
```

then change your function to be this

```
    @Override
    public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {

        super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
        watchFace.setAntiAlias(!inAmbientMode);

        if(inAmbientMode)
        {
            watchFace.setTimeColor(Color.BLACK);
            watchFace.setDateColor(Color.GREY);
        }
        else
        {
            watchFace.setTimeColor(Color.RED);
            watchFace.setDateColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
```

When the watch is put into **Ambient Mode** the screen turns itself black and white (or black and grey as you're experiencing)

> Note: In low-bit ambient mode, the system does not reliably render the
>   colors in the image

from [The Android Webpage](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/performance.html)

Comment: How would you create a new watch face depending on what mode I am in

Comment: Alright I editted my answer, look at Edit 2.  Please let me know if it doesn't work, and if it does work please accept my answer.

Comment: No problem! I might have switched around the colors a little bit but you know how to change them if need be.  And good idea keeping dark colors which will help save the battery on the watch.